# Wrong App.Config publish.targets MSBuild 15

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2017, msbuild-15

I posted this question on GitHub/Microsoft/MSBuild but I'm hoping the wider community might have some early experience with this.

I'm working on converting a solution / projects from VS 2015 (.NET core preview) to VS 2017 and latest .NET Core.

The solution now builds perfectly fine in Visual Studio 2017 but the issue I encounter is when trying to run a build using MSBuild 15 (I can't use v14 because of the .NET Core projects). It fails on trying to copy the .config file from the obj\debug\net452 folder but for some reason it's adding the full .csproj name

The issue is that the Publish.Targets are doing something weird with the .config file.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\build\Microsoft.NET.Publish.targets(128,5):
error MSB3030: Could not copy the file "obj\Debug\net452\Sitecore.Foundation.Commerce.Engine.csproj.code.exe.config" because it was not found. 

[C:\Projects\Sitecore.Demo.Retail\src\Foundation\Commerce\Engine\code\Sitecore.Foundation.Commerce.Engine.csproj]
```

It's prepending the full project name (including .csproj) to the name of the config file rather than just using the AssemblyName.

In this case, Sitecore.Foundation.Commerce.Engine.csproj is the project and code is the AssemblyName (it will eventually be renamed to something better). As you can see it's looking for "Sitecore.Foundation.Commerce.Engine.csproj.code.exe.config" which doesn't exist. code.exe.config does exist though.

I'm happy to give GitHub repo access to anyone interested in helping figure this one out with me as it's blocking us from making the repository public.

so code.exe.config is resolved as Sitecore.Foundation.Commerce.Engine.csproj.code.exe.config

OUTPUT snippet from MSBuild:

```
08:13:09.957     1>Target "GenerateBindingRedirectsUpdateAppConfig: (TargetId:127)" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets" from project "C:\Projects\Sitecore.Demo.Retail\src\Foundation\Commerce\Engine\code\Sitecore.Foundation.Commerce.Engine.csproj" (target "ResolveReferences" depends on it):
                   Set Property: AppConfig=obj\Debug\net452\Sitecore.Foundation.Commerce.Engine.csproj.code.exe.config
                   Added Item(s): 
                       AppConfigWithTargetPath=
                           obj\Debug\net452\Sitecore.Foundation.Commerce.Engine.csproj.code.exe.config
                                   TargetPath=code.exe.config
```

Here is the Sitecore.Foundation.Commerce.Engine.csproj content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net452</TargetFramework>
    <PreserveCompilationContext>false</PreserveCompilationContext>
    <AssemblyName>code</AssemblyName>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <PackageId>code</PackageId>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <!--<ItemGroup>
    <None Update="wwwroot\**\*">
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>-->

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\legacyCommerce\Plugin.Sample.Habitat\Plugin.Sample.Habitat.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\legacyCommerce\Plugin.Sample.Payments.Braintree\Plugin.Sample.Payments.Braintree.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\legacyCommerce\Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.AdventureWorks\Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.AdventureWorks.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics" Version="1.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration" Version="1.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel" Version="1.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console" Version="1.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData" Version="6.0.0-alpha1-rtm-121216" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights" Version="2.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog" Version="2.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Sitecore.Commerce.Core" Version="1.0.2301" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Literate" Version="2.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.RollingFile" Version="3.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Filter" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Extensions.Logging" Version="1.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="1.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Sitecore.Commerce.Provider.FileSystem" Version="1.0.2301" />
    <PackageReference Include="Sitecore.Framework.Rules" Version="1.1.12" />
    <PackageReference Include="Sitecore.Framework.Rules.Serialization" Version="1.1.12" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Sitecore.Framework.Diagnostics" Version="1.1.4" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'net452' ">
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: Link to GitHub issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/1873

Answer (score 0):

It turns out one of our NuGet references had a dependency on an incompatible package. This in turn manifested itself in a very weird way.

I'm sorry if this doesn't help anyone else but this seems to have resolved our specific issue.